# PUT calls with Breeze.js

Tags: breeze, put

I was looking at Breeze.js and was interested in using it with services that we have in production. The services are already working and cannot be changed.

The question I had was if it is possible for Breeze.js to make PUT calls when saving data? If so, are there any examples showing how?

Answer (score -1):

We are working on providing more documentation for this, please stay tuned.

Comment: Does that mean the functionality exists, but just needs documenting? Or is this functionality which is yet to be delivered?